# Не срабатывает настройка "NAT" в виртуальной машине VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Настраиваю Ubuntu 20.04.1 на виртуальной машине VirtualBox, но имеется такая проблема. Выставляю в настройках "Сеть NAT", при этом в результате входа в систему нет интернета. Настройки: Сеть - Подключение - Адаптер1 - "Сеть  NAT" (тип подключения). Хост - Windows 8. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Что конкретно означает «нет интернета»? Какие настройки сети в гостевой ОС? Виден ли сетевой адаптер, выдался ли IP-адрес (`ip addr`)? Используется ли какой-нибудь менеджер сети (NetworkManager) или всё вручную?

Comment: Интернета нет - не открывается значех Firefox. Пишет нет соединения с интернетом .  Тип подключения - сеть "NAT". Вручную.

Comment: «Вручную» — и какие именно настройки вы задали вручную?

Comment: Ну не то чтобы вручную - DNS-серверы IPv4 и IPv4, они заданы.

Comment: Во-первых, какие конкретно они заданы? Во-вторых, по умолчанию для сети NAT в VirtualBox работает DHCP-сервер, который выдаёт IP-адреса автоматически — почему бы не использовать его?

Comment: Указаны порт и адрес, в настройках сети подключен VirtualBox Host-Only Network.

Comment: В настройках сети в принципе не бывает никаких портов, да и непонятно, какое отношение Host-Only имеет к NAT. В общем, абсолютно непонятно, что там у вас происходит, и без внятного разъяснения ситуации вы вряд ли сможете получить здесь помощь...

Comment: Ну просто я немного "заклинился" с этой задачей =)